# Text Justification using PathListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

We have an applicaiton where we have to draw text on various curved lines.  We have been evaluating using the PathListBox class from sample on [Microsoft Design Tutorial PathListBox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/textonapath.aspx).

We have the basics running as shown in the demo and it works well.  Our problem is that we need to be able to center the text on the path and we do not see a way to do this.  Normal justification doesn't work in this case because each letter is drawn as it's own ListBoxItem with a TextBlock as the template along the path.

Suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an immediate way of achieving this.

There is the `Start` property, which will determine the point (as a percentage) at which the items start to be displayed. You could use this to center static content, but if the text is subject to change, it won't work.

If you have Blend, you can easily create a copy of the template and inspect and modify it. I'd look to see if the actual container holding those `TextBlock`s is inside something else, and if it is, you might be able to set its alignment to center.

Comment: I forgot to add one thing in my problem description.  The text I have to justify is dynamic within the application (as is the path).  So we have to be able to figure out how to do this on the fly.  I'll take a look at the Start Property.

Comment: Start Property gets us most of the way towards solving the problem.  Thanks.